# Trying to sort a list of dictionaries in side another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I need to sort a list of dictionaries to able to compare the data.

- I tried the sort() function of list
- I tried sorted(My_dict["IndividualDUC"][List hardware], key=lambda x: x[1])

***Dictionary before sort***

```
  My_dict = {'IndividualDUC':
     {'List hardware':
      [
        {'AMDEVBOS': {'Group': 'Default','Version': 'Not installed'}}, 
        {'ATM0-IT-QAV1': {'Group': 'IT', 'Version': 'Not installed'}}, 
        {'ATM0-PEO-QAV2': {'Group': 'PECO', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}}, 
        {'ATM0-PEO-QAV1': {'Group': 'PECO', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}}, 
        {'MSTQA-ITQA-VM2': {'Group': 'msGrp1', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}}, 
        {'ATM0-IT-QAV2': {'Group': 'IT', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}},
      ]
     }, 
     'DUCPercentages': 
      {'List hardware': 
        {'Not installed': {'Percentage': '18.2', 'Count': 2}, 
         '10.0.40219': {'Percentage': '81.8', 'Count': 9}
        }
      }
    }
```

***Expect the output:***

```
reuslt = {'IndividualDUC': 
 {'List hardware':
  [
    {'AMDEVBOS': {'Group': 'Default','Version': 'Not installed'}}, 
    {'ATM0-IT-QAV1': {'Group': 'IT', 'Version': 'Not installed'}}, 
    {'ATM0-IT-QAV2': {'Group': 'IT', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}}, 
    {'ATM0-PEO-QAV2': {'Group': 'PECO', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}}, 
    {'ATM0-PEO-QAV1': {'Group': 'PECO', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}},          
    {'MSTQA-ITQA-VM2': {'Group': 'msGrp1', 'Version': '10.0.40219'}}, 
  ]
}, 
'DUCPercentages': 
  {'List hardware': 
    {'Not installed': {'Percentage': '18.2', 'Count': 2}, 
     '10.0.40219':    {'Percentage': '81.8', 'Count': 9}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what was the actual output? What minor version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6.4. The list in the key 'List hardware' must be sorted.

Comment: Show how you attempted to sort the lists. Provide runnable examples please.